# Weird artifacts in image generated by multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I was intrigued by the [Raytracing in One Weekend book](https://raytracing.github.io/books/RayTracingInOneWeekend.html) by Peter Shirley, and have been coding along in C++. I finished the first book and got the same result. I wanted to speed it up by spreading the tracing over multiple threads, which seems to be working. However, I noticed that I get some artifacts, sort of streaks, at the bottom edges of my images.

Here are the bottom-left corners of two rendered images:

- [What it looks like normally (no threading)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eydlM.png)
- [What it looks like with 16 threads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7han.png)

The streaks seem to appear only at the bottom of the image, and I've found that the streaks worsen when I increase the number of threads. I have 16 threads available hardware-wise, if I increase it to say 64 (which doesn't make sense but still) I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAKwK.png), way more streaks. I have tried for hours to identify what the problem is, but cannot seem to find what is causing it.

I have tried locking (using mutex) the entire function that is executed by each thread, which I thought should give the same result as not using threads at all, but I still get the artifacts.

**Here is (the important part of) my code**

The function that each thread is executing grabs a line from the image that is not done yet and goes through each pixel to determine its color (taking multiple randomized samples every pixel):

```
void worker() {
   while (done_count < image_height) {

      // grab the y-value of the line to parse
      int y = done_count++;
      {
         std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
         std:cerr << y << std::endl;
      }

      // go through each pixel in the line and shoot multiple rays
      for (int x = 0; x < image_width; x++) {
         color pixel_color(0, 0, 0);
         for (int s = 0; s < samples_per_pixel; s++) {

            auto u = (x + random_double()) / (image_width - 1);
            auto v = (y + random_double()) / (image_height - 1);
            ray r = cam.get_ray(u, v);
            pixel_color += ray_color(r, world, max_depth);
         }

         // write the result of each pixel to image_buffer
         image_buffer[y * image_width + x] = pixel_color;
      }
   }
}
```

The function that this relies on is `ray_color`, which takes the starting ray and a world/scene, and figures out what color that would result in after bouncing around:

```
color ray_color(const ray& r, const hittable& world, int depth) {
   hit_record rec; // this stores hit data such as distance and material
   
   // stop if max. recursion depth is reached
   if (depth <= 0) return color(0, 0, 0);
   
   // check if an object in the world is hit (between 0.001 and infinity)
   if (world.hit(r, 0.001, infinity, rec)) {
      ray scattered;
      color attenuation;
      
      // use the hit object to determine where the ray is directed to next
      if (rec.mat_ptr->scatter(r, rec, attenuation, scattered)) {
         return attenuation * ray_color(scattered, world, depth - 1);
      }
      return color(0, 0, 0);
   }
   
   // if nothing is hit, return a color from a blue-white color scale
   vec3 unit_direction = unit_vector(r.direction());
   auto t = 0.5 * (unit_direction.y() + 1.0);
   return (1.0 - t) * color(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) + t * color(0.5, 0.7, 1.0);
}
```

Putting this all together results in the main code (using threading):

```
// Setup
const int image_width = 400;
const int image_height = 400;
const int samples_per_pixel = 50;
camera cam(lookfrom, lookat, vup, dist_to_focus, aperture); // excluded creation of these
hittable_list world = random_scene();

std::atomic<int> done_count{ 0 };
static std::mutex m;
shared_ptr<color[]> image_buffer(new color[image_height * image_width]);


color ray_color(...) ...
void worker() ...


int main() {
   // init threads (number depends on hardware)
   int n_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
   std::cerr << n_threads << std::endl;
   std::vector<std::thread> threads;
   
   // start threads
   int new_thread_index = 0;
   while (new_thread_index < n_threads && new_thread_index < image_height) {
      threads.emplace_back(std::thread(worker));
      new_thread_index++;
   }
   n_threads = (int)threads.size(); // intended and actual number of threads could differ
   
   // wait for all threads to finish
   for (std::thread& thread : threads) {
      thread.join();
   }

   // code here to divide each color by samples_per_pixel and save to file (did not include)
   ...

   std::cerr << "Done!" << std::endl;
}
```

To not use threads, I can simply replace the `main` function with this (practically the `worker` function in a for-loop):

```
int main() {
   for (int j = 0; j < image_height; j++) {
      for (int i = 0; i < image_width; i++) {
         color pixel_color(0, 0, 0);
         for (int s = 0; s < samples_per_pixel; s++) {
            auto u = (i + random_double()) / (image_width - 1);
            auto v = (j + random_double()) / (image_height - 1);
            ray r = cam.get_ray(u, v);
            pixel_color += ray_color(r, world, max_depth);
         }
         image_buffer[j * image_width + i] = pixel_color;
      }
   }
}
```

For what it is worth, I am running this through Visual Studio 2022 on Windows using the C++20 language standard.

**Edit**
Two functions that are called during from `worker` and `ray_color`:

```
ray cam::get_ray(double s, double t) const {
   vec3 rd = lens_radius * random_in_unit_disk(); // random vector in disk
   vec3 offset = u * rd.x() + v * rd.y();
   return ray(origin + offset, lower_left_corner + s * horizontal + t * vertical - origin - offset);
}

bool hittable_list::hit(const ray& r, double t_min, double t_max, hit_record& rec) const {
   hit_record temp_rec;
   auto hit_anything = false;
   auto closest_so_far = t_max;

   for (const auto& object : objects) {
      if (object->hit(r, t_min, closest_so_far, temp_rec)) {
         hit_anything = true;
         closest_so_far = temp_rec.t;
         rec = temp_rec;
      }
   }
   return hit_anything;
}
```

Comment: How are you synchronizing each thread's access to `done_count`? IIUC, that represents the index of the latest unprocessed line in the image, which means its access must be synced across threads, most easily by putting it behind a mutex.

Comment: Seems that the image_buffer[y * image_width + x] = pixel_color; is undefined behavior as some wrong y values go to std::cerr. Why you don't tell that in your question?

Comment: @bnaecker yes this is correct, it is basically the index of the next row of pixels. I thought std::atomic made incrementing it thread-safe, and I had the same worry so tried putting it in the mutex block but that didn't seem to change the result

Comment: @ÖöTiib I am not sure I understand what you mean, the way I see it is I place the calculated pixel_color into image_buffer which stores all pixels in a 1D fashion, so I calculate the index using `y*image_width + x`

Comment: Ahh, my bad, I missed that that was an atomic. I was confused by the order of things here, with lots of the definitions below. That should be thread-safe.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Oh I think I might understand, the logging of `y` to `std::cerr` is not because it is an error, but because in the book `std::cout` is used to create the final file, which this value should not go in.

Comment: And there are none wrong y values in std::cerr? Did you look carefully

Comment: @ÖöTiib I doubted it too so I saved the log to a txt file and checked with Python but every y is called once and exactly once (0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 398, 399). The first 16 are somewhat out of order (probably due to threads starting at different times) but after that it is all exactly +1 each time.

Comment: And just to be sure, the methods `cam.get_ray` and `world.hit` don't modify any shared state?

Comment: Then likely there is race condition of some internal state of random_double() that causes strange side effects.

Comment: @bnaecker I don't think so, added them as an edit to the post

Comment: @ÖöTiib that could be the case, the random_double is there to act as a sort of anti-aliasing, I'll try to remove it and do it without the randomness to see if the streaks still show up

Comment: @ÖöTiib found the problem now! My `random_double` function was indeed not thread-safe and causing problems (still weird that it only happened at the bottom edge), I am using a thread-safe method now and the streaks are gone :) Thanks, and also thanks to @bnaecker!